# Google Sheets ( I need to count the production on a certain date. I may have up to 10 entries with units of gallons produced)

Tags: google-sheets, countif, sumifs

[image: First Screen Shot]

[image: Second Screen Shot]

I want the total gallons blended on 1/3/24. The first ss is the cell where I want the total and the second is the list of the daily entries on 1/3/24. I want it to total all entries on a specific date not just 1/3/24. See attached.

Comment: use the [`SUMIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en) function. It's impossible for us to write a formula because you cropped out the column labels, row numbers and sheet names.

Comment: Can I send an excel spreadhsheet for you to see

Comment: you can share the link here or [make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: Related questions: [Is there a way to use SUMIF when you are searching date formatted cells? Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68671270/1330560), [How to use SUMIF with VLOOKUP based on Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58653484/1330560). The last question shows how absolute references should be used for the "sum range" and the "criteria range".